# How can a sock gets into a washer's drain boot

Tags: washing-machine

My beloved Kenmore front loader washer cannot drain water yesterday after 10 years of not so heavy use.  I opened it up, thinking I may need to replace the drain pump, but I saw a sock in the drain boot.  I am going to put everything back tomorrow and try it again to see if it fixes the issue by removing the sock.

I am wondering how can a sock gets into the drain boot.  Is it a sign that I need to change the door seal boot as well?

[image]

Comment: So that's where my socks have been disappearing into...

Comment: Is it possible some one put the sock there as a drain filter? As I doubt it could have came to be there from inside the washing machine.

Comment: @DanD. if the gap between the drum and the housing is large enough then it's not impossible for a sock to get caught in the edge and pushed towards the drain.

Comment: Blame the underwear elves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The washing machine consists of what is effectively a barrel with a spinning cage inside.  That cage is where the clothes go.  There is a gap between the top of the cage and the barrel.

If the gap between the top of the cage and barrel were big enough, and the washer were carelessly loaded, then a small item could easily fall behind the cage into the barrel, where it would get sucked into the drains.

Comment: It seems as though everybody is too busy arguing with me to up vote the answer.  Voting up, and clearing comments to reduce distraction.